# How to reference incrementing variables in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create 200 matrices of dimensions 200 X 129. I have a bit of code that needs to run over the 200 matrices, but each new matrix references the previous one.

```
for(i in 1:200)
{
  nam <- paste("step", i, sep = "")
  mat<- matrix(ncol=129, nrow=200)
  assign(nam, mat)
  stepg<- matrix(ncol=129, nrow=200)
  stepg<- step[i][200,129]
  index<-sample(1:nrow(stepg), 2)
  }
```

When I run this code, I get an error "Error in step[i][20, 30] : incorrect number of dimensions". I want to know how to reference the ith matrix.

Comment: What is `step[i]` supposed to be?  Suppose you are on the 10th iteration such that `i=10`, then are you trying to access the object `step10`?

Comment: Forget for now that `assign` exists. Do `step <- list()` before the loop and then instead of using `assign` do `step[i] <- matrix(ncol=129, nrow=200)`.

Comment: @DanY, yes, i am trying to access ith step; ie, step10

Comment: @Roland, when I use list, I get the error "incorrect number of dimensions" when I sample using  'stepg<-step[i]' and the error "argument of length 0" when I directly try to sample using '1:nrow(step[i])'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not altogether sure what the question is asking, but you might find this concept helpful: instead of creating matrices with unique names such as `step1` and `step2`, you can store these objects as elements in a list:

```
storage_list <- vector(mode="list", length=200)
for(i in 1:200) {
    storage_list[[i]] <- matrix(...)
}
```

Then you can easily access, e.g., `storage_list[[i-1]]`.

Answer (score -3):

Table = data.frame(matrix(vector(), 129, 200,dimnames=list(c(),c("nam","mat"))),stringsAsFactors=F)

I Think these might help you