# I want to assign and store a new value for each iteration in a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, networking

I want to assign and store a new value into the R environment for each iteration of a for loop as said in the title.

```
csg<-clusters(suba)

csgs1<-subgraph(suba, csg$membership==1)

sg1<-cluster_spinglass(csgs, weights=E(a)$weight)
```

So, given some igraph object (suba), I want to create sg1, sg2,..., sg31. I don't want to go through the 2 lines of code above 31 times though so I've tried a for loop? But I don't know how to store a new value each time.

```
for (k in 1:seq_along(length(csg$csize))){

  csgs[k] <- subgraph(suba, csg$membership==k)

  sg [k] <-cluster_spinglass(csgs[k] , weights=E(a)$weight)

  }
```

Obviously, the square brackets don't work in this situation but I couldn't find how to do this.

Ideally, I'd want to have sg1,sg2, etc saved into the R environment so that I could use these as the groups for my network suba. Because my code is straight up not working, I don't get results at the moment. It works individually though, creating a subgraph for csgs1 and a list for sg1.

Comment: See my "store as list elements" answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878574/how-to-reference-incrementing-variables-in-r/54915389#54915389) for one simple approach

Comment: Also, you should initialize a loop with `for(k in 1:length(vec))` or even better with `for(k in seq_along(vec))`. Right now, your code does `1:seq_along(length(vec))` which is effectively `1:1` and -- I suspect -- not what is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to really have multiple variables created, then you can do it as follows:

```
for (k in seq_along(csg$csize)){
  assign(paste0("csgs",k), subgraph(suba, csg$membership==1))
  assign(paste0("sg",k), cluster_spinglass(get(paste0("csgs",k)), weights=E(a)$weight))
}
```

This will create you `csgs1`, `csgs2`, `csgs3`, etc. and `sg1`, `sg2`, `sg3`, etc., so that you can use them directly later in your code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was pretty much just looking for the paste0 thing. :)

Comment: I have updated the answer to achieve what you exactly want. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you store things as list instead of flooding your environment with multiple objects.

However, you could use `assign` to create a new object and assign a value like:

```
assign("a", 10) #Create an object "a" and assign value 10
a
[1] 10
```